# Create New Cubit Class in Android Studio 4.2.1

Tags: android, visual-studio-code

Good day I am following a tutorial and part of it requires me to create a cubit class, the teacher is using VS Code and the extension to create Cubit Classes can be easily be found. I found the one for Android Studio, installed it and the feature showed but it would not create the class still.

Comment: Add bloc library

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The plugin that I installed was not compatible with Android Studio 4.2.1, I had to download Android Studio Artic Fox build +145, repeated the process and now it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

install the Bloc plugin in the plugins of the IDE settings